# Using:JavascriptConverter in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm currently serializing objects like this:

```
public static string ObjToJson(List<MyObject> TheObjects){

  JavascriptSerializer TheSerializer = new JavascriptSerializer();
  TheSerializer.RegisterConverters( new JavascriptConverter [] { new ObjectToJson() });
  string JsonObj = TheSerializer.Serialize(TheObjects);
  return JsonObj; }
```

And then I have this:

```
public class TheObjToJson : JavascriptConverter{
 public override IDictionary<string,object> Serialize (object obj, JavascriptSerializer serializer)
    {
    ...
     return jsonstring;
    }
}
```

Is this the fastest/best way to do JSON in [ASP.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET)?

Comment: how about dynamically creating json string and render it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the most popular JSON library is [json.net](http://www.codeplex.com/json). It's fast and easy to use.